# Asana one calendar across multiple projects

Tags: calendar, tasks, asana

I have clients invite me to their Asana projects and I would like to see one list/calendar of all the tasks assigned to me across all of these projects. Is there no way of doing this?

It seems you need to go into each project individually and then see what items has been assigned to you.

I have a looked and searched and resorted to emailing them directly as I cannot find a forum for Asana either.

Answer (score 1):

Click the `My Tasks` button, and then open the Calendar there, you will see all your day-specific tasks there. Let me know if you can't find it, I will post a screenshot.